# How to make the Apple MapKit VR flyover in ARKit framework?

Tags: mapkit, augmented-reality, arkit, virtual-reality

I'm trying to see if it is possible to have the Apple Maps VR Flyover [displayed here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/06/24/ios-11-maps-vr-mode/) but instead of in VR, have it in AR with ARKit.

I'm aware the map data can be accessed within MapKit but not able to extract the map and 3D building data into ARKit in order to, for example, place the 3D model of a city on my table by detecting a surface.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=499iX4_ifHw